# Disable drag and drop and Enable select in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have came through with this strange issue when i select the text it is also draggable and even dropable on anyother text and it concatenates with it. i have overcome with this problem by doing like,

```
ondragstart="return false" onmousedown="return false"
```

but it also disables the selection like in future to do a copy/paste. I want to disable drag and drop of text and enable the selection of text.

Comment: This is just a browser feature, you can drag and drop text on facebook! Is there a specific reason you don't want this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use only `ondragstart="return false"`. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLYGF/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's this, not to sure though not really played with it:

```
<div draggable="false">Drag and Drop</div>
```

Note: This is a new feature for HTML5, will not work with earlier versions of HMTL